# Prove $k!(e-s_k)$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Given that $\frac{p}{q} = e = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + ... + \frac{1}{k!} + \frac{e^{z}}{(k+1)!}$ for some $z$ in $[0,1]$ (using Taylor's theorem), and that $s_k = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + ... + \frac{1}{k!}$ prove $k!(e-s_k)$ is irrational.

I have no idea how to start this - all hints appreciated.

Comment: at least you should be able to see what $k! (e-s_k)$ is..

Comment: You should also be to put bounds on $e^z$

Comment: @Henry : I am not very sure how does it help to see bounds on $e^z$... could you please eloborate.

Comment: $p/q$ is never equal to $e$.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a variant of [Proof that e is irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational) ?

Comment: @lhf the question leads up to it, and is broken up to parts - this is the only bit i cannot do

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $m,n\in \mathbb Z$ and $a$ is irrational then $m(a-n)$ is irrational because $m(a-n)=r\in\mathbb Q$ implies $a=r/m+mn\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: this would be a basis for my proof, but i have trouble getting to the part reaching some sort of contradiction that $\frac{e^z}{(k+1)!}$ is irrational

Comment: @user73229, perhaps you could include the whole proof strategy in your question.